# How can I apply discrete wavelet transform to decompose the PCA components with 9 levels?

Tags: python

I'm trying to analyze signal data. I have applied PCA with 10 components. I have 2d matrix form package[100000,10] I would like to apply level 1 discrete wavelet transform. I have looked at the python website but I still don't get it. Could someone provide me some codes with a bit of explanation how to apply DWT to the package data I have? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seem you need this [PyWavelets lib](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/dwt-discrete-wavelet-transform.html)

Install by: `pip install PyWavelets`